# When building a lightswitch app I got " Error 11 Could not copy <path to lightswitch dlls> Exceeded retry count of 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012, lightswitch-2012

While building a lightswitch app I kept getting this error:

Error 11 Could not copy "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\LightSwitch\Client\Microsoft.LightSwitch.dll" to "Bin\Debug\bin\Microsoft.LightSwitch.dll". Exceeded retry count of 10. Failed. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\LightSwitch\v2.0\Microsoft.LightSwitch.targets 150 10

It did not make sense to me so I tried copying the files manually, it did not work.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the application name on the "General Properties" page to something shorter and that did the trick!

Answer (score -1):

open task manager then choose "Processes" tab then you will find your project actually running , press on end process button then re-run your project 
have fun ;)

Comment: The user appears to have already answered the question, and this answer seems completely unrelated to the problem.